# How to disable "automatically manage signing" in Xcode 8

Tags: cordova, xcode8

My Xcode project in Xcode 8 has a check in "automatically manage signing" as a default.
How can I disable it by using CLI, not Xcode, because my Cordova-based app has to be built by Jenkins.

After opening the Xcode project, I disable the check and execute the below command for building.
It works but the manual process should be automatic.

```
xcodebuild -project "/platforms/ios/test.xcodeproj" -sdk "iphoneos10.0" -configuration "Release" -scheme test ENABLE_BITCODE="NO" install DSTROOT="/target/debug" DEVELOPMENT_TEAM="teamId" PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="teamId/provisioningProfileName"
```

Answer (score 2):

We are using automatically managed signing with Xcode 8 and Cordova through Jenkins. I wrote about how we set it up here:
https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html

To recap, you need to specify your developer team ID. In the next version of Cordova-iOS, you can do this with `developerTeam` in your build.json file. I have [a hook](https://gist.github.com/dpogue/186b6c1827363c48d644b0d59e91bc28) available in the meantime.

You also need to set your code signing identity to "iPhone Developer", **even for release builds**. Do this with `codeSignIdentity` in your build.json.

You should not need to specify a provisioning profile, Xcode will automatically handle that when it has the team ID.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  
I want to get not only an app for development but also one for OTA.  
I built my app in the same way which you taught me and got an app built with iOS Team Provisioning Profile.  
In this case, is it possible to distribute the app as OTA?  
In Xcode 7.3.1, an app for development has a provisioning profile for development and, on the other hand, an app for OTA has one for Ad Hoc.  
So, there is a difference between apps built by Xcode 8.0 and 7.3.1.  
To share an app with the team members, I have to realize OTA.

Comment: Yes, to make an Ad-Hoc build, you'll need to run the Archive step. That will automatically take the development identity and replace it with the distribution identity.  
  
If you're running via the command-line xcodebuild, see https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/migrating_code_signing.html#building-for-distribution-xcode-8